# Excel: Group rows and add minimum and maximum from two different columns within the group

Tags: excel, group-by, pivot

I have the following excel table:

```
+-------+----------+------------+----------+
| event | category | start-time | end-time |
+-------+----------+------------+----------+
| a     | Z        |          0 |        9 |
| a     | Z        |          2 |       10 |
| a     | Z        |          2 |       11 |
| b     | Y        |          2 |        7 |
| c     | X        |          3 |        8 |
| c     | X        |          2 |        7 |
| c     | W        |          4 |        8 |
| c     | W        |          5 |       10 |
+-------+----------+------------+----------+
```

I need to group the rows by event and category and then find the start and end-time of that event-group and finally calculate the time difference. Resulting in the following table:

```
+-------+----------+------------+----------+------+
| event | category | start-time | end-time | time |
+-------+----------+------------+----------+------+
| a     | Z        |          0 |       11 |   11 |
| b     | Y        |          2 |        7 |    5 |
| c     | X        |          2 |        8 |    6 |
| c     | W        |          4 |       10 |    6 |
+-------+----------+------------+----------+------+
```

Is there an elegant solution, without using VBA?

Comment: Did you tried pivot table?

Comment: you mean using the min, max functions and than calculating the difference?
This works if you only need to do one grouping. But with multiple grouping it will not work since you will have a row for each column that you are grouping.

Comment: @valenzio Pivot table works just fine with your data.  Just drag both event and category to the Rows area; then do the Min start and max end times in the values area.  Suggest using Tabular form for layout, but you can experiment with the various design options.

Comment: you are right, but at the end I need to calculate the overall time. Which is not feasible since you have additional rows, and you have to include the group names in your formula. (I edited my question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish your goal with Power Query, available in Windows Excel 2010+ and Office 365.

To use Power Query

- Select some cell in your Data Table
- `Data => Get&Transform => from Table/Range`
- When the PQ Editor opens: `Home => Advanced Editor`
- Make note of the Table **Name** in Line 2
- Paste the M Code below in place of what you see
- Change the Table name in line 2 back to what was generated originally.
- Read the comments and explore the `Applied Steps` to understand the algorithm

**M Code**

```
let

//read in the raw data
//change table name in next line to actual table name in your workbook
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table17"]}[Content],

//set appropriate data types
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{
        {"event", type text}, {"category", type text}, {"start-time", Int64.Type}, {"end-time", Int64.Type}
            }),

//Group by event and category
//extract min start time and max end time
//calculate time duration
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"event", "category"}, {
        {"Start", each List.Min([#"start-time"]), type nullable number}, 
        {"End", each List.Max([#"end-time"]), type nullable number},
        {"Time", each List.Max([#"end-time"]) - List.Min([#"start-time"]), type nullable number}
        })
    
in
    #"Grouped Rows"
```

[image]

---

If your version of Excel has the `UNIQUE` and `FILTER` functions, you can do this with formulas:

eg:

```
A29:    =UNIQUE($A$8:$B$15)
C29:    =MIN(FILTER($C$8:$C$15,($A$8:$A$15=A29)*($B$8:$B$15=B29)))
D29:    =MAX(FILTER($D$8:$D$15,($A$8:$A$15=A29)*($B$8:$B$15=B29)))
E29:    =D29-C29
```

*Select C29:E29 and fill down*
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Pivot table will give you desired result.

[image]

If you want to do it by formula then use below formulas.

```
E2=UNIQUE(A2:A7)
F2=MINIFS(B2:B7,A2:A7,E2#)
G2=MAXIFS(C2:C7,A2:A7,E2#)
```

[image]

Comment: This works if you only need to do one grouping. But with multiple grouping it will not work since you will have a row for each column that you are grouping.

Comment: Then post those sample data with multiple column.